# Search multiple words through php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm new in php. I can search through one keyword not by two. I want to search using multiple words e.g "first+experience"

while entry in database feild is as "First_Experience"

I use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fh_Names WHERE fh_Sid LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";
```

Also this query is for single table, I want to search data through multiple tables. (joining or some otherway). Please tell me query

I mean User name from fh_Name table and its activity from fh_Activity table

Comment: Are table fh_Name and fh_Activity correlated by any key?

Answer (score 0):

Then explode the string and try this

```
$str = "first+experience";
$expl = explode("+", $str);

$implode = (",", $expl);

$query = "SELECT * FROM fh_Names WHERE fh_Sid IN($implode)";
```

Comment: I need another query to search from 2 tables by matching user name from fh_Name with its activity from fh_Activity